# How to change file content in all commits on BitBucket?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

So, I found that I have a hardcoded confidential data in one .json file and I am trying to find a solution how to change data in all previous commits, so I want to put that confidential data to .env file. Can I do it in some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do git filter-branch --tree-filter.
You can refer to this https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/